# IBM Websphere webservice call from Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: web-services, websphere-8

While calling web service from WebSphere 8.5.5 facing below issue:

```
at com.ibm.wsdl.DefinitionImpl.getAllServices(DefinitionImpl.java:873)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.util.WSDLWrapperReloadImpl.getAllServices(WSDLWrapperReloadImpl.java:903)
    at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.util.WSDLDefinitionWrapper.getAllServices(WSDLDefinitionWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.wspolicy.wsdl.internal.subject.DefinitionSubjectProcessor.<init>(DefinitionSubjectProcessor.java:60)
    at com.ibm.wspolicy.wsdl.internal.WSDLProcessorImpl.buildWSDLPolicyModel(WSDLProcessorImpl.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.wspolicy.wsdl.WSDLProcessor.<init>(WSDLProcessor.java:137)
    at com.ibm.ws.wspolicy.policyset.WSDLHelperImpl.processWSPolicyInPackagedWSDL(WSDLHelperImpl.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.deployment.WASAxis2PolicySetConfigurator.associatePolicySets(WASAxis2PolicySetConfigurator.java:385)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.client.WSClientConfigurationFactory.completeAxis2Configuration(WSClientConfigurationFactory.java:459)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.<init>(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.EndpointDescriptionImpl.<init>(EndpointDescriptionImpl.java:223)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.updateEndpointDescription(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:534)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.updateEndpoint(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.updateEndpoint(DescriptionFactory.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.getPort(ServiceDelegate.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegate.getPort(ServiceDelegate.java:513)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:99)
```

Webservice call is working in java standalone project.
Till `WASAxis2PolicySetConfigurator.java` am able to debug and not able to find below jar file for class

```
com.ibm.ws.wspolicy.policyset.WSDLHelperImpl.processWSPolicyInPackagedWSDL
```

Comment: You cut off the actual exception with message, add it to the stacktrace

Comment: printed above error in my logger file.